# kernel: how to add a new source file for kernel build?

Tags: kernel

For an academic project, I'm looking to add a source file (myfile.c) to the `kernel/` directory, the same directory as `exit.c` and `fork.c`. The build system does not appear to automatically pick up the new file, as I'm hitting "undefined reference" link errors to functions defined in `myfile.c`. How could I get this file incorporated?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to add a corresponding object file to the `kernel/Makefile`. If you have a configuration variable for your code, then you would use:

```
obj-$(CONFIG_ZERO_STIMULUS_FEATURE) += zerostimulus.o
```

If you're building in your code without a configuration variable, then you'll just add it to the `obj-y` variable:

```
obj-y += zerostimulus.o
```

The configuration variable expands to `y`, `m`, or `n`, depending if the feature is built-in, built as a module, or turned off. Then the `obj-y`, `obj-m`, variables are built.

Answer (score 4):

That's right!

Just an addendum: Before building the kernel, you know that running "`make menuconfig`" you can set which features will be build-in the kernel image (**y**) , which will be enabled as a loadable module (**m**) and which will not be enabled (**n**).

if you want to be able to set it for your new feature you will be able to do it editing the **Kconfig** file that you will find in the same folder of the new file. In your case "`linux-x.y.z/kernel/Kconfig`"

This is an example:

```
config ZERO_STIMULUS_FEATURE
    tristate "My new feature"
    default m
    ---help---
      This is my brand new feature
      Here's a multi-line description
```

A usual mistake is to set "`config CONFIG_ZERO_STIMULUS_FEATURE`" instead of "`config ZERO_STIMULUS_FEATURE`": Don't add here the prefix "`CONFIG_`"

If your feature is not loadable as a module, then you will have to use the "`bool`" keyword instead of "`tristate`". Take a look at other Kconfig files and you will also see how easy is to set dependencies.

Best regards,
/Angel